# Should Name Claim remain omitted in JWT Access Token with IdentityServer4 (using Identity) and ASP.Net Core API?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

While configuring my IdentityServer4 (using Identity) resource owner grant flow with an asp.net core API backend, I got to thinking that perhaps the "Name" claim should remain omitted in the JWT access token for user security? This claim is not available with out of the box behavior of IS4.

Previously, I had been adding in the "Name" claim for the access token in my IS4 Config.cs file as follows:

```cs
var claims = new List<string>
{
    JwtClaimTypes.Name
};

return new List<ApiResource>
{
    new ApiResource("api1", "Auth API", claims)
};
```

I was doing this because it allows a straightforward approach to get a logged in user's ClaimsPrincipal.Identity.Name for user look up inside a Controller action.

```cs
var name = User.Identity.Name;
var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(name);
```

However, IS4 access tokens (when using Identity) include the user's GUID id in the "Sub" claim. With this, we can also look up a user using the following:

```cs
var userId = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Type == "sub").Value;
var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
```

I know there is slightly more processing with the LINQ query (hardly anything tbh), but I was thinking it might be of worth to protect a user's username (email address in my situation) if an access token ever fell into the wrong hands. Especially since JWT's are so easy to decode with the likes of [jwt.io](http://jwt.io).

Do you guys agree or disagree? Or am I looking at this the wrong way and missing something?

Answer (score 1):

JWT usually contain the public data and it is self-contained. i.e. You don't need to communicate with a backend server to construct user's identity. You should prevent the token fell into wrong hand by using https. Also, you should balance your token validity window(usability vs security) and use a nonce for maximizing the security.

I don't think 'name' should be omitted from claim collection. A valid use-case for what you are doing is that you need to make sure that changes to your user store immediately reflect in your web API. In the case of a self-contained token, if you change the 'name' in the data store, the user will not see that change until he was issued a new token. In this case use of a 'reference token' might be a good option.

Also, It looks like you are directly accessing user store from the web API. While you might have valid reasoning behind this, Idea of using token based authentication is to delegate authentication to external party(Identity Server). So common pattern is to

1. Include every public data that you require in the web API in the
   access token.
2. If token getting too big, include a subset of claims in the token and query user info endpoint when required.
3. Use [reference tokens](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/reference_tokens.html) if you have valid reasons to do so. But this will affect the performance as it will require back channel communication with identity server.

Comment: How does a nonce increase security?

Comment: A nonce is used in the authorize endpoint that issues the tokens after authenticating the users. http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDTokenValidation. The nonce is used to mitigate the replay attacks. It is not increasing the security of the token, but prevent a malicious user from getting the token by replaying a form already submitted by someone else.

Comment: I'm agreeing with @rawel, that you should not remove the `name` claim. If someone else has your `access_token` you have a much bigger problem, than just someone having your email address. Also an email address is not something hideable, since basically it was created to give it away to people.

Comment: @moritzg. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @rawel thanks for the input. Your reply helped me connect the dots in that the token should be the user's identity with no need for server lookup for validation. And indeed, your use-case (in the 2nd paragraph) is something I had thought of why "name" should be removed. However, I could keep "name" in the jwt and just invoke the use of a refresh token whenever a user changes their email address - thus issuing a new access token. :)

Comment: @DJDJ Please note that refresh token and reference token are two different things. Refresh tokens are used to allow offline access on behalf of a user and reference tokens are pointers to the real access token. I haven't tested how they behave when you change unique claim like email. So I can't really recommend any approach. Please share your approach/experience regarding that.

Comment: Regarding "no need for server lookup for validation": Even though token is self-contained, token validation(using IDS's public key) must be done.  You can do that by acquiring public key at startup from metadata endpoint and using that public key for validation without communicating with IDS again. Sending the access token to token validation endpoint in IDS is another option to make sure token is valid. Using standard client library will do the validation for you. But make sure you know their options as to do inline validation or remote validation.

Comment: @rawel, yea - I know refresh and reference are different. For refreshing the access tokens on an email change - when using Angular, after the http promise is returned successful, I have the app automatically request a new access token using the refresh token, thus sending me a new token with updated claims. I'm not sure if this is the "official" way of doing this, but it has worked in sample apps. However, I don't see it being any different than getting a new access token after expiration (especially since access tokens should be short lived).

Comment: Sound reasonable. But you should use refresh tokens only on the server side of your app. Use of refresh tokens in client angular app is not secure as you need to store client credentials on the angular app which make those credentials public.